# Suppress "Check Names" pop-up box when sending

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using the following code to send a file to an Outlook contact group I created myself which has a unique name, e.g. "List Europe":

```
Public Function Sendout(strRecipients As String, strSubject As String, 
strPDF As String) As Boolean

Dim wbCC    As Workbook
Dim wsMain  As Worksheet
Dim wsSO    As Worksheet


Set wbCC = Workbooks("Control-Center.xlsm")
Set wsMain = wbCC.Worksheets("Main")
Set wsSO = wbCC.Worksheets("Sendout")

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

If strPDF <> "" Then
    wsSO.Activate
    wsSO.Range("A1:B1").Select

    With Selection
        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

        With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
            .Item.To = strRecipients
            .Item.Subject = strSubject & strDate
            .Item.Attachments.Add strPDF                
            .Item.Send
        End With

        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False
    End With

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Sendout = True
    Else:   Sendout = False
End If

End Function
```

When running my code, the "Check names" box pops up and offers more than just the list I handed over to my function, but other lists containing the words "List" and/or "Europe", e.g. "Europe second list".

My question is, how can I suppress this pop-up and force the code to use just exactly what I handed over? Manipulating settings in Outlook where you - in theory - can disable such messages did not result in any success.

Thanks!

Comment: Any thoughts/help would be much appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: A shot in the dark: rename your contact group to `List_Europe` (i.e. no spaces).

Comment: Thanks @Andre, I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Though clear names would be preferred; otherwise, I would have named my lists from e.g. 1 to 10...

Comment: @Andre, worked as expected. So thanks again! Still I'd like to find out why handing over a string does not resolve. Will try what Dmitry Streblechenko suggested as well and see what can be done.

Comment: I guess it's one of the many cases where Office wants to be helpful but fails. `List Europe` - oh, he wants a contact containg "List" and "Europe", let's list them all. Isn't that nice of me? -- `List_Europe` - oh, there is only one contact matching "List_Europe", so let's resolve it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use names for recipients. Use SMTP addresses - they are always unambiguously resolved.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry Streblechenko, where would I find the SMTP address? I created that list by myself in Outlook, it's a user-defined list which has no entry in the company address book. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean it is a distribution list in Outlook? But the data in your code comes from Excel, does it not?

Comment: True. Excel is used to send the mail, the list is a user-defined list in Outlook. Works perfectly fine for single users, a seperated list of users, global address book lists and unser-defined lists which have a unique name.

Comment: Well, does not work too well if the name is ambiguous, right? How are the name entered? By hand? Or programmatically?

Comment: `strRecipients` hands over the string which is inserted into the "To" field programmatically.

Comment: Do not use the To/CC/BCC properties - in general, they only contain display names. Loop through the Recipients collection and for each recipient, read the Recipient.Address property (you might need to use Recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress for the EX recipients).

Comment: Thanks, that sounds promising - will give it a try!